# malloc: *** error for object: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug in Magical record IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

When ever I am trying to insert the data using **MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject** my App crashes:

> malloc: error for object 0x174291c0e: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list.
>   Set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

Code where it crashes is:

```
+ (NSArray *) MR_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSError *error = nil;

        results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (results == nil) 
        {
            [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];
        }

    }];
    return results; 
}
```

Stack frame -

```
#0  0x000000018ac3a014 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x000000018ad02450 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x000000018abae3e0 in abort ()
#3  0x000000018ac7ea38 in nanozone_error ()
#4  0x000000018ac80bf0 in _nano_malloc_check_clear ()
#5  0x000000018ac7fbb4 in nano_calloc ()
#6  0x000000018ac71180 in malloc_zone_calloc ()
#7  0x000000018ac710c4 in calloc ()
#8  0x000000018a6af510 in class_createInstance ()
#9  0x000000018a6bdae4 in _objc_rootAlloc ()
#10 0x000000018df40298 in -[NSSQLGenerator generateSelectIntermediateInContext:] ()
#11 0x000000018df3f584 in -[NSSQLGenerator generateIntermediatesForFetchInContext:countOnly:] ()
#12 0x000000018e04c314 in -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:nestIsWhereScoped:requestContext:] ()
#13 0x000000018e04e940 in -[NSSQLiteAdapter _statementForFetchRequestContext:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] ()
#14 0x000000018e04eaf4 in -[NSSQLiteAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequestContext:ignoreInheritance:] ()
#15 0x000000018e0fb820 in -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext _createStatement] ()
#16 0x000000018e0fb790 in -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext fetchStatement] ()
#17 0x000000018e0fc8fc in -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] ()
#18 0x000000018e010e98 in __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke ()
#19 0x0000000101dc121c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#20 0x0000000101dcde38 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#21 0x000000018e010d34 in -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] ()
#22 0x000000018e0d6ec4 in -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] ()
#23 0x000000018e03fd04 in -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] ()
#24 0x000000018e03abc4 in -[NSSQLCore processFetchRequest:inContext:] ()
#25 0x000000018df3d518 in -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#26 0x000000018e01d844 in __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#27 0x000000018e015f90 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] ()
#28 0x000000018df3d1cc in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#29 0x000000018df3bbf4 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
#30 0x000000018dfecb90 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] ()
#31 0x000000018dfed398 in __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#32 0x000000018dfef640 in internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#33 0x0000000101dc121c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#34 0x0000000101dcde38 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#35 0x000000018dfdc9b0 in _perform ()
#36 0x000000018dfed088 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#37 0x000000018df3bbf4 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
#38 0x00000001013df24c in __67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke at /Users/Desktop/Core Data/glider/Pods/MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:54
#39 0x000000018dfe1b70 in developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#40 0x0000000101dc121c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#41 0x0000000101dd1e5c in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke ()
#42 0x0000000101dc121c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#43 0x0000000101dc6284 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#44 0x000000018bc17f2c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#45 0x000000018bc15b18 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#46 0x000000018bb44048 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#47 0x000000018d5ca198 in GSEventRunModal ()
#48 0x0000000191b302fc in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#49 0x0000000191b2b034 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Please provide me some hint.

Comment: Post the crash log or full backtrace (after setting that breakpoint).

Comment: I have updated crash stack frame

Comment: Oh, joy.   You got yourself a memory smasher somewhere.   Look for buffer overflows and the like.   Unfortunately, the point where malloc() figures out that things have gone off the rails is way too late.

Try turning on Malloc debugging in Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

If getting response data in form of **objects in array** then its good that we should use

```
let defaultcontext = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
Entityname.MR_importFromArray(listOfObjectData: [[NSObject : AnyObject]], inContext:defaultcontext) 
defaultcontext.MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
```

instead of inserting by iterating one object and then save it the

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a class method ([MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];) from within a block. Move the whole if (!results) check outside the block and many problems will be prevented.